# Custom date format iseries access odbc for SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008

How to resolve my issue below?
1. I am pulling data from AS/400 DB2 using (iseries access odbc driver) to SSRS.
2. I want to format the column stores in integer to date format.
Sample = 20180612 below is the SQL Query.
Using below query,

```
SELECT  CHAR(DATE(SUBSTR(DIGITS(20180612),1,4)||'-'||
        SUBSTR(DIGITS(20180612),5,2)||'-'||
        SUBSTR(DIGITS(20180612),7,2)),ISO) AS RESULTSDATE
```

Output = 2018-06-02

Question: How can I produce a below custom date format like d/m/yyyy
I have used, ISO, USA, LOCAL, JIS, EUR but no yield.

Example: 2/6/2018

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it already. I just format it to the date without formatting.

```
SELECT DATE(SUBSTR(DIGITS(MIN(DTAHRS.HREMCP.EMREDT)),1,4)||'-'||
        SUBSTR(DIGITS(MIN(DTAHRS.HREMCP.EMREDT)),5,2)||'-'||
        SUBSTR(DIGITS(MIN(DTAHRS.HREMCP.EMREDT)),7,2)) AS RESULTSDATE
```

After that, I put this as sub-query so that I can pass this to the parameter.
Below is my whole query, then at SSRS I can use date/time parameter control to compare with the results.

```
SELECT x.RESULTSDATE
FROM (  SELECT DATE(SUBSTR(DIGITS(MIN(DTAHRS.HRLVTP.LTLDTE)),1,4)||'-'||
        SUBSTR(DIGITS(MIN(DTAHRS.HRLVTP.LTLDTE)),5,2)||'-'||
        SUBSTR(DIGITS(MIN(DTAHRS.HRLVTP.LTLDTE)),7,2)) AS RESULTSDATE
    ) as x
WHERE x.RESULTSDATE >= ? AND x.RESULTSDATE <= ?
```

I hope it will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in SQL Server, the closest you can CONVERT it to is the USA 110 (mm-dd-yyyy) in SQL Server.

If the your dataset has a field with the 2018-06-02, you can use the **CDATE** function is **SSRS** to convert it to a date and then format the text box the way you want with the **FORMAT** property or the FORMAT function.

Format Function:

```
=FORMAT(CDATE("2018-06-02"), "M/d/yyyy")
```

Format Property of Text Box:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

/* this is as close as I can come to the desired results there is a leading zero */

```
select                                        
varchar_format(                               
timestamp_format(char(20180612), 'YYYYMMDD')  
, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as resultdate                              
  from my8digitdatetable
```

/* for export IRL send out a date */

```
select                                        
cast(                               
timestamp_format(char(20180612), 'YYYYMMDD')  
as date) as resultdate                               
  from my8digitdatetable
```